# Pinging all subnets of a wireless network

Tags: networking, scripting

I'm trying to satiate my curiosity by doing a small network reachability test. I want to try to ping all subnets of a wireless network at my school from the subnet that I am connected to. So, suppose the network has 4 subnets (a,b,c,d) and I am connected to 'a', I want to try to ping at least 1 computer in subnets 'b','c', and 'd'. Once I have finished pinging, I want to connect to the next subnet (b) and repeat this process until I've connected to all subnets and tested all the other subnets.

I read some of the other similar threads and a lot of people suggested nmap as a very robust tool for network testing. Is it applicable to my case? How should I go about doing this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try tp do a boardcast ping.  But most routers and operating systems will ignore the request.  You might also try to ping the access points instead of the computer nodes.

Comment: That actually seems to be more what I'm looking for. What would you suggest as the means for going about doing this?

Comment: If you can do a boradacst ping you would just ping the network broadcast address.  For example on a 24bit network it would be something like 10.1.2.255.  Any client that can reply to a boardcast ping would ping back.  But again most routers and operating systems block this because it can be used in hacking attacks.